# Looping a calculator code

Tags: java, validation, loops, if-statement, calculator

I have this calculator code that uses both the users postfix expression and also a file input depending on the users preference, i need to create a loop that, if any of the postfix expression is incorrect, (3 3  +, 3 x 3,34 43 43 etc.) it already gives the user a correct error message regarding the error, but i need it to start the loop again for both the file input and the keyboard input, starting from the beginning where the user types in k or f for which input they would like.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press K to enter the input using the keyboard. Press F to read expressions from a file");
    String option = Scanner.nextLine();
    while (!(option.equalsIgnoreCase("K") || option.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))) {
        System.out.println("Invalid option - please choose again");
        option = Scanner.nextLine();
    }
    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) {

        Scanner Scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a postfix expression: ");

        String line = Scanner2.nextLine();

        String[] elements = line.split(" ");

        if (elements.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);

        }

        else {
            try {
                // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with
                // "exceptions"

                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

                double answer = 0;
                boolean OpperationWrong = false;
                String operation = elements[2];
                switch (operation) {

                case "+": {
                    answer = (num1 + num2);
                    System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                }
                    break;

                case "-": {
                    answer = (num1 - num2);
                    System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                }
                    break;

                case "/": {
                    answer = (num1 / num2);
                    System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                }
                    break;

                case "*": {
                    answer = (num1 * num2);
                    System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    OpperationWrong = true;
                }
                String ans;
                if (OpperationWrong) {
                    System.out.println("Please use +,*,/,- for your operator");
                } else {
                    ans = String.valueOf(answer);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Key entered, please enter a number for first 2 elements");
            }
        }
    } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {

        try {
            Scanner Scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the file name to read expressions from : ");
            File file = new File(Scanner3.nextLine());
            Scanner3 = new Scanner(file);

            while (!(file.exists())) {
                System.out.println("Error: That file does not exist, please re-enter: ");

            }

            String line;

            while (Scanner3.hasNext()) {
                line = Scanner3.nextLine(); // read the next line of text
                                            // from the file
                String[] elements = line.split(" ");
                if (elements.length != 3) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);
                } else {
                    try {
                        // "try" is a statement which allows us to deal with
                        // "exceptions"

                        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

                        double answer = 0;
                        boolean OpperationWrong = false;
                        String operation = elements[2];
                        switch (operation) {

                        case "+": {
                            answer = (num1 + num2);
                            System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                        }
                            break;

                        case "-": {
                            answer = (num1 - num2);
                            System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                        }
                            break;

                        case "/": {
                            answer = (num1 / num2);
                            System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                        }
                            break;

                        case "*": {
                            answer = (num1 * num2);
                            System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                        }
                            break;

                        default:
                            OpperationWrong = true;
                        }
                        String ans;
                        if (OpperationWrong) {
                            ans = " Please use +,*,/,- for your operator";
                        } else {
                            ans = String.valueOf(answer);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid expression please enter a number for first 2 elements");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("The file could not be found");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585160/create-a-java-calculator/33585372#33585372

Answer (score 0):

## A Few Things

It looks like you can utilize functions here in a very powerful way to solve your problem. I also noticed you may want to look closer about how you are using and naming your variables.

## Functions

Functions or Methods are an extremely important part of any programming language, when you can do *something* and find yourself wanting to do that *something* again, this is how you can identify where you want a function or method.

You've done the hard part above in that your code does what you want it to do. Now you want to do it again, so we can think about this action as calling a function.

You may want to add the ability to quit out of the function if the user presses 'X' or something similar, and i'll leave that exercise up to you if you choose to implement it.

## Variables

There are a few instances where you initialize a variable when you already have access to it, most obvious to me is the Scanner. When you declare and initialize `Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`, this gives you access to System.in for as long as you have access to the Scanner variable ( another tip is to use lowercase letters to name your variables, where Scanner and Scanner are ambiguous later on as to if you're referring to the variable or the class). Later on doing `Scanner Scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in)` is unnecessary.

There are some other clean ups you can do with variables, but again i'll leave them up to you.

## Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean quitting = false;
        while (!quitting){
            quitting = processInput(scanner);
        }
    }

    public static boolean processInput(Scanner scanner){
        System.out.println("Press K to enter the input using the keyboard. Press F to read expressions from a file");
        String option = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!(option.equalsIgnoreCase("K") || option.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid option - please choose again");
            option = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a postfix expression: ");

            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            String[] elements = line.split(" ");

            if (elements.length != 3) {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);

            }
            else {
                try {
                    // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with
                    // "exceptions"

                    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

                    double answer = 0;
                    boolean OpperationWrong = false;
                    String operation = elements[2];
                    switch (operation) {

                    case "+": {
                        answer = (num1 + num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                    }
                        break;

                    case "-": {
                        answer = (num1 - num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                    }
                        break;

                    case "/": {
                        answer = (num1 / num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                    }
                        break;

                    case "*": {
                        answer = (num1 * num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                    }
                        break;

                    default:
                        OpperationWrong = true;
                    }
                    String ans;
                    if (OpperationWrong) {
                        System.out.println("Please use +,*,/,- for your operator");
                    } 
                    else {
                        ans = String.valueOf(answer);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Key entered, please enter a number for first 2 elements");
                }
            }
        } 
        else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter the file name to read expressions from : ");
                File file = new File(scanner.nextLine());
                Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

                while (!(file.exists())) {
                    System.out.println("Error: That file does not exist, please re-enter: ");

                }

                String line;

                while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                    line = fileScanner.nextLine(); // read the next line of text
                                                // from the file
                    String[] elements = line.split(" ");
                    if (elements.length != 3) {
                        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);
                    } 
                    else {
                        try {
                            // "try" is a statement which allows us to deal with
                            // "exceptions"

                            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

                            double answer = 0;
                            boolean OpperationWrong = false;
                            String operation = elements[2];
                            switch (operation) {

                            case "+": {
                                answer = (num1 + num2);
                                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                            }
                                break;

                            case "-": {
                                answer = (num1 - num2);
                                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                            }
                                break;

                            case "/": {
                                answer = (num1 / num2);
                                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                            }
                                break;

                            case "*": {
                                answer = (num1 * num2);
                                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                            }
                                break;

                            default:
                                OpperationWrong = true;
                            }
                            String ans;
                            if (OpperationWrong) {
                                ans = " Please use +,*,/,- for your operator";
                            } 
                            else {
                                ans = String.valueOf(answer);
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid expression please enter a number for first 2 elements");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
                System.out.println("The file could not be found");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having an while(true) loop and break if input is acceptable.

A simple Example:

```
int input=0;
while(true){
input =new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); 
if(input<=0){
System.out.println("Illegal input!");
continue;
}
break; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NB:
-You should use lower case letter for the name of variable in JAVA like `Scanner scanner`.
-You should use one Scanner for each source for example `System.in` or `new File("name of file")`.
-For Scanner from Keyboard (System.in), it's recommended to use a `static` Scanner variable like: `private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`.
-You should close your Scanner when you use Scanner with the path File `Scanner(File source)`

If you want to loop again from the beginning, you can try to use a infinity loop `while(true)` like that:

```
public class Test {
// lower case of name variable
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
while(true){
System.out.println("Press K to enter the input using the keyboard. Press F to read expressions from a file");
String option = scanner.nextLine();
while (!(option.equalsIgnoreCase("K") || option.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))) {
    System.out.println("Invalid option - please choose again");
    option = scanner.nextLine();
}
if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) {

    System.out.println("Please enter a postfix expression: ");

    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] elements = line.split(" ");

    if (elements.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);

    }

    else {
        try {
            // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with
            // "exceptions"

            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

            double answer = 0;
            boolean OpperationWrong = false;
            String operation = elements[2];
            switch (operation) {

            case "+": {
                answer = (num1 + num2);
                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
            }
                break;

            case "-": {
                answer = (num1 - num2);
                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

            }
                break;

            case "/": {
                answer = (num1 / num2);
                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

            }
                break;

            case "*": {
                answer = (num1 * num2);
                System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
            }
                break;

            default:
                OpperationWrong = true;
            }
            String ans;
            if (OpperationWrong) {
                System.out.println("Please use +,*,/,- for your operator");
            } else {
                ans = String.valueOf(answer);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Key entered, please enter a number for first 2 elements");
        }
    }
} else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {

    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the file name to read expressions from : ");
        File file = new File(scanner.nextLine());
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file);

        while (!(file.exists())) {
            System.out.println("Error: That file does not exist, please re-enter: ");

        }

        String line;

        while (scanner1.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner1.nextLine(); // read the next line of text
                                        // from the file
            String[] elements = line.split(" ");
            if (elements.length != 3) {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid Expression: " + line);
            } else {
                try {
                    // "try" is a statement which allows us to deal with
                    // "exceptions"

                    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);

                    double answer = 0;
                    boolean OpperationWrong = false;
                    String operation = elements[2];
                    switch (operation) {

                    case "+": {
                        answer = (num1 + num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                    }
                        break;

                    case "-": {
                        answer = (num1 - num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                    }
                        break;

                    case "/": {
                        answer = (num1 / num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);

                    }
                        break;

                    case "*": {
                        answer = (num1 * num2);
                        System.out.println("Answer is: = " + answer);
                    }
                        break;

                    default:
                        OpperationWrong = true;
                    }
                    String ans;
                    if (OpperationWrong) {
                        ans = " Please use +,*,/,- for your operator";
                    } else {
                        ans = String.valueOf(answer);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid expression please enter a number for first 2 elements");
                }
            }
        }
//            close your Scanner
     scanner1.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("The file could not be found");
    }
}
}
}
}
```