# Create a java calculator

Tags: java

One of the questions on my assignment is to create a Calculator program to implement a solution which asks users to input a line of text containing a post-fix expression. The program should validate the input then evaluate this showing the expression evaluated (using infix notation) and the result. 
If validation fails then a suitable error message should be shown. For example,Error: Invalid expression.

This is my code so far: (How do i change the code so theres a loop where the user should be repeatedly prompted to enter an expression until they input an empty line, i.e. press return with no input, at which point the program should terminate?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                System.out.println("Enter a post-fix expression of the form 3 5 *:");
                double n1 = scanner.nextDouble();
                double n2 = scanner.nextDouble();
                String operation = scanner.next();

                switch (operation)  {
                case "+":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 + n2));
                    break;

                case "-":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 - n2));
                    break;

                case "/":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 / n2));
                    break;

                case "*":
                    System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 * n2));
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You originally tagged this JavaScript. Java and JavaScript are not the same, make sure you learn the difference so you avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: You've asked how do you add a loop. What loop do you think is appropriate if you want to keep executing while the user has not entered certain input?

Answer (score 1):

Write inside a while loop.

```
while(true) {
   System.out.println("Enter a post-fix expression of the form 3 5 *:");
   double n1 = scanner.nextDouble();
   double n2 = scanner.nextDouble();
   String operation = scanner.next();
   switch (operation ) {
         case "*":
           // Do operation
           continue;
         case "+":
           // Do operation
           continue;
         case "":
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This checks if the operator, after two doubles, is empty.  (I submitted an edit for basic syntax fixes.)

Comment: @DavidDuncan Thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your requirements the next code should work fine. 
It will check if you pressed enter. I'm also checking for exceptions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a post-fix expression of the form 3 5 *:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!line.equals("")) {
            try {
                Scanner scannerInternal = new Scanner(line);

                double n1 = scannerInternal.nextDouble();
                double n2 = scannerInternal.nextDouble();
                String operation = scannerInternal.next();
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":
                        System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 + n2));
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 - n2));
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 / n2));
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        System.out.println("Your answer is " + (n1 * n2));
                        break;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid expression.");
            }
            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap your logic with a while loop. Something like:

```
bool get_user_input = true;
while(get_user_input){
Scanner ... 
.... switch(operation){
....}
if(user_input_satisfies){
get_user_input = false; //your finished getting input from scanner
}
```